# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' HTML scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributeerror

I'm trying to do my first web scrapping with amazon website but I'm facing an error that i couldn't solve it. this is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
# import libaries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# Connect to website 

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Hanes-Short-Sleeve-Beefy-T-Smoke/dp/B01KNM3EAM/ref=sr_1_4?crid=5ZT2DA0EILMA&keywords=t+shirts+for+man&qid=1692275014&sprefix=t+s%2Caps%2C422&sr=8-4'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64de10e0-49a614555bcfb2fc5d15488a"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "lxml")

title = soup2.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

print(title)
```

The code returns an error - nontype object has no attribute 'get_text' - and if run it without the get_text attribute it returns: None.

this is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [42], in <cell line: 14>()
     10 soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
     12 soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "lxml")
---> 14 title = soup2.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
     16 print(title)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

PS. the productTitle id does exist and have a text inside:

```
<span id="productTitle" class="a-size-large product-title-word-break">  "Hanes Mens Beefyt T-Shirt, Classic Heavyweight Cotton Crewneck Tee, Roomy Fit, 1 Or 2 Pack, Available in Tall" </span>
```

i have seen the answer of this question in this website but all were no help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you might get redirected to a CAPTCHA type page if you 'request' too much so it is not scrapping the data you think. Look at `soup2.text` before doing the find and check what the text actually is.

Answer (score 0):

While scraping programmatically using the requests library, they can easily identify and block such activity. however with selenium, a web automation tool, we can accomplish this task.

try this code :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Hanes-Short-Sleeve-Beefy-T-Smoke/dp/B01KNM3EAM/ref=sr_1_4?crid=5ZT2DA0EILMA&keywords=t+shirts+for+man&qid=1692275014&sprefix=t+s%2Caps%2C422&sr=8-4'
chrome_driver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(URL)

product_title_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]')
product_title = product_title_element.text

print(product_title) # Output: Hanes Mens Beefyt T-Shirt, Classic Heavyweight Cotton Crewneck Tee, Roomy Fit, 1 Or 2 Pack, Available in Tall


driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with `X-Amzn-Trace-Id`. There's no need to use it if you are not planning to trace your requests.  The following code works

```
# import libaries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Connect to website 
URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Hanes-Short-Sleeve-Beefy-T-Smoke/dp/B01KNM3EAM/ref=sr_1_4?crid=5ZT2DA0EILMA&keywords=t+shirts+for+man&qid=1692275014&sprefix=t+s%2Caps%2C422&sr=8-4'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.188"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, features = "html.parser")
title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
print(title.text.strip())
```

```
Output:
Hanes Mens Beefyt T-Shirt, Classic Heavyweight Cotton Crewneck Tee, Roomy Fit, 1 Or 2 Pack, Available in Tall
```